# Adding custom tabs to product page based on attribute set

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to get a Part listing tab to show only on products with a attribute set of kit. I managed to get the tab to show on all pages by adding:

```
  <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.new.tab" as="new.tab" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Parts Listing</value></action>
   </block>
```

I would like to load a unique CMS block for each product with related content so it can be edited from the backend. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Edit for clarification:
Ultimately I would like to have a store with kits and parts. Once you click on a kit it would have a tab for a listing of all the separate parts available. I was thinking of just using a category and population a list based on the category ID.(makes it easy for store admin to make changes) If you are looking a part this tab wouldn't be available.